# MySQL- inserting a date into a varchar and then converting back to date when querying

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have to use a varchar field in a mysql database to store a date, and I need to be able to query on this date later on as if it was a date field.

1. What format should the date go into the database? `date()`?
2. How do I convert a string to a date in mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean you wanna convert that whole column, or copy the value from that VARCHAR column to a new real date() column?

Comment: "I have to use a varchar field in a mysql database to store a date" --- elaborate this. Why "have to"?

Comment: So the date will be stored in a varchar column. I want to be able to do `SELECT 'x' from a where {varchar date column} >= CURDATE()`

Comment: I have to because I am using Wordpress' `add_option` to store my settings and these are kept as varchar's in the database.

Comment: If you've access to the database, why not change its type to `date`?

Comment: I have your answer for you, exactly as you have written above...

Comment: i read a presentation at effectivemysql.com, they said to avoid data conversion simply because it drains the query performance,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQL` provides [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) data type. But `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` should be fine, depending on what you need.

For the format, this is the standard format as per [wiki](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_MySQL%27s_default_DATE/DATETIME_format?). `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, for date only, this should do: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Also check out the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

Here is an example:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y')`

will return a date of

`'2013-05-01'`

Answer (score 2):

As i seen from your comment you are using wordpress so in that already have function to use date with format which you want

use below [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)  to `get_option` and also have default parameter to get. like

```
<?php echo get_option( $option, $default ); ?>
```

where `$default = 'date_format' - Default date format; set in General Options.`

let me know if i can help u more.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

STR_TO_DATE()

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna query the data, as if it was a date, you can do it like this...

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(yourColumn,'%m/%d/%Y %x:%x:%x'), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') >= NOW()
```

This will select all readocrds that have a date greater than or equal to today

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no problem. If you like to store a date as varchar, it is okay. If you like to use the data with date functions later, it is also okay. The difference is only in the way MySQL stores the data. If you use varchar to store a date, you need more memory, but you can store other strings too. You can try it yourself:

```
mysql> SELECT YEAR("2013-06-18");
+--------------------+
| YEAR("2013-06-18") |
+--------------------+
|               2013 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

You can even compare strings with dates like this:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(NOW())="2013-06-18";
+--------------------------+
| DATE(NOW())="2013-06-18" |
+--------------------------+
|                        1 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

If you don't trust this tests, you can first put the data into a test table with a field of type varchar. I have done it with the same result.